# Kafka bootstrap.servers config value as subset of brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, spring-kafka

For kafka bootstrap.servers config one should provide all the broker details.

If not, how does kafka producer/consumer will resolve all brokers available?

If yes, Do producer/consumer needs restart after adding a node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootstrap.servers config is mandatory for producer and consumer and it must have one broker host:port at least in order to allow producer/consumer to connect to the cluster and then getting all the other metadata (where topics are, who are the leaders and so on).

If you add a node, you don't need to restart producer/consumer but of course the current configuration will be stale. I mean ...
If you have a cluster with broker1 and broker2 and you put them into the bootstrap.servers config then producer/consumer connect to the cluster.
Let's imagine that you add broker3 and some new topics/partitions are deployed there. Your producer/consumer will be able to write/read to/from these new topics/partitions because information about them (so that they are on broker3) will be available through asking metadata to broker1 or broker2.

Of course if you shutdown broker1 and broker2 and your cluster will be just made of broker3, you'll have to restart producer/consumer with the bootstrap.servers config with just broker3.

The bootstrap.servers config is just (as the name implies) a configuration used on starting; then each client will be able to connect directly to a broker (for reading/writing topic/partitions there) even if such broker isn't in the bootstrap.servers config.

Comment: If a broker is not publicly exposed and private to network and only one broker is exposed backed by elb, then producer/consumer should fail to communicate?

Comment: yes because even if you set the public broker in the bootstrap list but you have topic/partitions on a private broker (which is leader for them), then producer/consumer will try to open the connection there finally ... with no success.

Comment: But I am able to publish and consume successfully

Comment: it means that the topic/partitions you are send/receive are on the public broker

Comment: I am little confused here. is it work like activeMq failover(<brokers_list>)? where in which if not able to get a connection from one broker it will connect to the other one?

Comment: Yes .. I am able to send and receive

Comment: Absolutely not ... it's not like ActiveMQ failover. I think you should read more about on the Kafka documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/). Topics and related partitions are spread across the Kafka cluster, some brokers are leader for some partitions and not for others. A client needs to connect directly to the broker which is leader for a topic partition in order to send/receive to/from that partition. As I said, better to read the doc.

Comment: Thanks @ppatierno .. I realized can be solved with `advertised.listeners` property value..

Comment: But this parameter sets how the broker advertises itself to the cluster for clients. In any case, if it's private and not reachable the client can't connect to it.